# Programa de comparação entre vetores C++

Tags: array, c++, if, for, comparação

Fala galera tudo bem? Eu sou iniciante e to tentando construir um programa que compare dois vetores e caso todos os elementos dos dois vetores sejam. vou exemplificar pra ficar melhor...

vetor1 = 10, 20 , 30 e vetor2 = 10 20 30; então a saida vai ser: números iguais.

vetor1 = 10, 20, 20 e vetor2 = 10, 20, 15; então a saida seria: 10 20 e tbm dizendo esses foram os numeros iguais.

vetor = 10, 20, 30 e vetor2 = 15, 19, 4; então a saida seria: nenhum número igual.
o problema é que quando todos os numeros são iguais, alem dele dar a sair falando que todos são iguais ele tbm ta mostrando os numeros e não é para isso acontecer.

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

  int n;
  cin >> n;

  int vetorX[n], i, a,c[n];

  for(a=0; a<n; a++){
  cin >> vetorX[a];
  }

  int vetorC[10] = {19, 7, 14, 0, 11, 17};
  int cont =0, cont1 = 0, cont2 =0;
  
 
  for(i=0; i<n; i++){
      for(a=0; a<n; a++){
        //conta a quantidade de numeros iguais
          if(vetorX[a] == vetorC[i]){
            cont ++;
            c[n] = vetorX[a];
            cout << c[n];
          }
      }
  }

  if(cont >= 7){
    cout << "todos iguais";
  }

  if(cont > 1 && cont < n){
    cout << "numeros iguais:";  
  }

  if(cont == 0){
    cout << "nenhum igual";
  }

}
```

Comment: Me parece que se cont == 0 então não tem nenhum igual e se cont < 7 então existem alguns iguais mas não todos. Uma situação que deve analisar é qual o resultado será obtido caso exista repetição de algum elemento no(s) vetor(es) e o que fazer neste caso.

Comment: peguei sua dica do zero e deu certo e o resto tbm, mas se todos os elementos são iguais ele retorna que são iguais e exibe os números tbm e não quero que isso aconteça, quero que se todos os numeros forem iguais ele retorne que, todos são iguais, sem mostrar os números.

Comment: Não vejo o menor sentido em utilizar 3 comandos `if` com exatamente a mesma condição.

Comment: sim, nem me dei conta disso e tirei. O problema é que continua exibindo os números mesmo se todos os números forem iguais e não é pra rolar isso, seria o caso de botar uma condição pra ele só exibir os numeros se tiver alguma diferença?

Answer (score 1):

Olá, você pode postar o seu código no [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/) que fica mais fácil.

C++ tem uma série de técnicas pra facilitar sua vida

1 - No lugar de usar vetores "[]" use o vetor "std::vector" em C++

2 - Ele tem um monte de operadores sobrecarregados (==, !=, <, >, <=, >=) logo vc pode perguntar diretamente v1 == v2 ou v1 != v2.

3 - Ele tem inicialização por {} do mesmo jeito que os vetores []

```
    vector a = { 10, 20, 30, 40 };
    vector b = { 10, 20, 30, 40 };

    if ( a == b ) {  // pergunte diretamente se os vetores são iguais
       std::cout << "iguais";
    } else { 
       std::cout << "diferentes";
    }
```

4 - Aprenda a usar os algoritmos e containers da stl, já tem um algoritmo pronto [std::mismatch](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/mismatch) pra fazer o que você quer, e além disso, vc pode facilmente escrever códigos sem loops "for" ( mais legíveis )

O que você quer fazer é um pouco incomum: gerar uma saída com os valores iguais apenas se o vetor tiver algum número diferente ? Nesse caso você vai ter que passar 2 vezes nos vetores, uma pra ver se eles são diferentes e outra para gerar a saída caso sejam. Mesmo assim :

Exemplo completo https://godbolt.org/z/4j35nx

Lá no código vc vai ver "mismatch()" que deixa claro sua intenção de procurar o primeiro elemento diferente em 2 containers e também vai ver "copy" com ultimo operador cout, ou seja copia para a saída.

Fora isso tem o caso de um vetor ser um sub-conjunto do outro, a = { 10, 20 } e b = {10, 20,30} vc quer qual saída nesse caso ?

Abraços